# How to display a date with date-fns formatted in a Mui DatePicker as Thursday, January 13th

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

In this example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-datepicker-forked-xyunb?file=/src/DatePicker.js) I'm trying to get the date formatted as `dddd, MMMM Do` and the expected result should be like `Thursday, January 13th` but instead is `0013, January 13th`

As per `date-fns` documentation here [Date-fns format](https://date-fns.org/v1.30.1/docs/format), writing `dddd` should give me back the name of the day but I got instead 0013 and I don't understand why.

I need help on what is wrong with the way I'm writing the date format and get the name of the day instead of that 0013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a new version of date-fns https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format.
You may use `format="iiii, MMMM Do"`.